# Can I use Ubuntu Desktop to backup my files from a Windows 10 computer that won't let me login?

Tags: windows, login, backup

I have an HP computer running the developer build of Windows 10.  It did an update and now will not recognize my password, will not let me use my pin number and will not let me access the internet to update the password.  I found a recommendation on howtogeek.com to use Ubuntu Live to backup my files before completely reinstalling the operating system.  According to the article, there was an option to “Try Ubuntu without any change to your computer”.  The link went to the Ubuntu Desktop download.  Is this still an option with Ubuntu Desktop to "try" without changing the operating system.  My computer is currently a paper weight and I need to get it up and running and recover some of my data that was not recently backed up.  Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: yes ubuntu has the choice to try without installation.